# Replacement for SynchronizationContext.Send() in Portable Class Libraries

Tags: c#, multithreading, portable-class-library

I'm writing a Portable Class Library that is going to be used by WPF, Windows Phone and possibly WinRT apps and I'm doing some work on background threads that occasionally need to call back to the UI. I instantiate the classes doing this in the UI thread, so I can easily save the SynchronizationContext and use it to call back to the UI.

However, in PCL, SynchronizationContext.Send() is obsolete, because it's not supported by WinRT and SynchronizationContext.Post() (which runs asynchronously) is not always appropriate.

I figured I'd just wait until the delegate passed to Post() is run, but all my attempts ended with a deadlock if Post() was invoked from the same thread the saved SynchronizationContext referred to.

Now I've managed to fix this by checking if it's the same thread and just simply calling my delegate if it is, but the checks are incredibly ugly involving reflecting out the value of private fields of the API, so I thought someone could help me find a more proper way.

Here is my current code if you'd like to see some gore:

```
/// <summary>
/// Invokes the passed callback on this SynchronizationContext and waits for its execution. Can be used even if
/// SynchronizationContext.Send is not available. Throws the exceptions thrown in the delegate.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">the context to run the method</param>
/// <param name="d">the method to run</param>
/// <param name="state">the parameter of the method to run</param>
public static void InvokeSynchronized( this SynchronizationContext context, SendOrPostCallback d, object state )
{
    if ( !context.Match( SynchronizationContext.Current ) )
    {
        ManualResetEvent waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent( false );
        Exception error = null;

        // replicate SynchronizationContext.Send with .Post as Send is obsolete in the Portable Class Library
        context.Post( ( o ) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    d( o );
                }
                catch ( Exception exc )
                {
                    error = exc;
                }
                finally
                {
                    waitHandle.Set();
                }
            },
        state );

        waitHandle.WaitOne();

        if ( error != null )
        {
            throw error;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        d( state );
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Checks if the two SynchronizationContexts refer to the same thread
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sc1"></param>
/// <param name="sc2"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool Match(this SynchronizationContext sc1, SynchronizationContext sc2)
{
    if ( sc2 == null )
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if ( sc1 == sc2 || sc1.Equals(sc2) )
    {
        return true;
    }

    // check if the two contexts run on the same thread
    // proper equality comparison is generally not supported, so some hacking is required

    return sc1.FindManagedThreadId() == sc2.FindManagedThreadId();
}

/// <summary>
/// Finds the ManagedThreadId of the thread associated with the passed SynchronizationContext
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sc"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static int FindManagedThreadId(this SynchronizationContext sc)
{
    // here be dragons
    try
    {
        BindingFlags bindFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static;

        switch ( sc.GetType().FullName )
        {
            case "System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherSynchronizationContext":
                // sc._dispatcher.Thread.ManagedThreadId
                var _dispatcher_field = sc.GetType().GetField( "_dispatcher", bindFlags );
                var _dispatcher_value = _dispatcher_field.GetValue( sc );

                var Thread_property = _dispatcher_value.GetType().GetProperty( "Thread", bindFlags );
                var Thread_value = Thread_property.GetValue( _dispatcher_value, null ) as Thread;

                return Thread_value.ManagedThreadId;
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException( "ManagedThreadId could not be obtained for SynchronizationContext of type " + sc.GetType().FullName, e );
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException( "ManagedThreadId not found for SynchronizationContext of type " + sc.GetType().FullName );

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is just fine in a WinRT store or phone app.  Checking a few common profiles, I see no [Obsolete] attribute on the method.  Are you being misled by the documentation or do you have a profile that actually generates the warning?

Comment: I'm getting a warning with Profile158 (.NET 4.5, Silverlight 5, WP 8, Windows Store for Windows 8) and the documentation says so as well [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.send(v=vs.110).aspx#ddueExceptionsToggle).

Comment: @KáGé, can I just remember `Thread.ManagedThreadId` when you save a reference to the UI thread's `SynchronizationContext`?

Comment: @Noseratio That sounds promising! And then I could get the current thread's when its needed and no need for reflection... I'll try that tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: Synchronously blocking one thread while executing code on another is very often a bad idea. This is why javascript, WinRT/XAML, Silverlight, etc. (basically all the new platforms) don't expose ways to synchronously block the thread. Everything should be async. So while I realize that doesn't answer your question, it's something to think about. C# 5 makes writing async code very easy.

Comment: Don't forget to wrap your `ManualResetEvent` in a `using` block so that it's disposed when you're done. Also consider using `ManualResetEventSlim` as it's more lightweight.

Comment: @AndrewArnott Thanks! But for some weird reason, the slim version is not available in my library (even though it should be in the same assembly as the normal version...)

Comment: @Noseratio I tried it and it works! Make it an answer and I'll accept it. :)

Comment: @AndrewArnott I try to make as much of it async as possible, but where I use this, the original async code had all sorts of problems that are now seem solved.

Comment: I recommend as much as possible to *not* invoke code on the UI thread from a background thread. Use `await` (from the UI thread), `IProgress<T>`, or a message bus instead of explicitly invoking. You'll end up with far better SoC and testability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that `SynchronizationContext.Send` is being deprecated by Microsoft for a good reason. They really want the new Windows Store and WP8 apps to fully embrace asynchronous programming model and make the blocking code a thing of the past.

So, something that was:

```
void SendDataToUI()
{
    _synchronizationContext.Send(_callback, data);
}
```

Should now become:

```
async Task SendDataToUIAsync()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    _synchronizationContext.Post(a => 
    { 
        try
        {
            _callback(a);
            tcs.SetResult(Type.Missing);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tcs.SetException(ex);
        }
    }, data);

    await tcs.Task;
}
```

That said, I suppose you have your own good reasons to use `SynchronizationContext.Send` in your PCL library.

The first part of your logic looks good, and you could cut off the reflection part of it by simply memorizing the `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` of the UI thread, at the same place where you memorize the `SynchronizationContext.Current` of the UI thread. Then in your implementation of `InvokeSynchronized` you just compare it to the `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` of the current thread, and use `waitHandle.WaitOne()` if your are on non-UI thread.